# Should the return value of Rust functions be Result, Option, or return a generic type?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm new to Rust and don't know how to determine whether the return value of a function should be Result or Option, or whether it should return the type as is.

- `Option` is used to return a value that may not be available.
- `Result` is used to return the result of a process that may fail.
- In other cases, it returns the type as is.

I'm trying to understand it as above. Is this correct?
I would like to know if there are any detailed documents or blogs about coding in Rust.

Comment: Sounds about right. You might be trying to make it more complicated than it actually is!

Comment: The question doesn't appear answerable as currently stated. Do you have a concrete example of a function whose appropriate return type you're unsure of?